# Lucene.Net search for multiple terms accross multiple fields that exist in document

Tags: c#, lucene

Im using the Royal Mail's sample PAF file, this data has been imported to a database and the following fields indexed via my own Lucene indexer console application:

```
...

var doc = new Document();

doc.Add(new Field("id", item.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("postcode", item.Postcode, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("buildingname", item.BuildingName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

...
```

What I want to be able to do now, is provide either a partial or full postcode or buildingname, and get matches back, as long as either searched term exists loosely in each documents postcode or buildingname fields . So if the postcode/buildingname was:

> TE55 5TT Test Building

If I provided "TE55 Test" I'd expect that to come back.

**My search code**

```
var fieldsToAnalyse = new[] { "postcode", "buildingname" };

var finalQuery = new BooleanQuery();
var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, fieldsToAnalyse, _analyzer);

string[] terms = searchTerm.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string term in terms)
{
    var formattedTerm = term.Replace("~", "");

    var formattedTermWildcard = $"+{formattedTerm}~";

    finalQuery.Add(parser.Parse(formattedTermWildcard), Occur.MUST);

}

var searcher = new IndexSearcher(_indexDirectory, true);

var hits = searcher.Search(finalQuery,10);

foreach (var hit in hits.ScoreDocs)
{
    documents.Add(searcher.Doc(hit.Doc));
}

_analyzer.Close();
searcher.Dispose();
return documents;
```

Whats actually happening.

value of `finalQuery` is:

> {+(+(postcode:test~0.5 buildingname:test~0.5)) +(+(postcode:te55~0.5
>   buildingname:te55~0.5))}

I'm getting back addresses that have a postcode which contains "te55" but `buildingname` is empty. I need it to both have a postcode that contains "te55" and the building name contain the word "test".

**Sidenote**

If i only provide one search term, i get:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.'

Which is also stumping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to create queries programmatically (not through parsing) and also from the string version i could see that your clauses are both should (no signs around them).

As a reminder - Lucene boolean syntax is following:

```
+ must clause
<empty> should clause
- not clause
```

In your case you have

```
postcode:te55~0.5 buildingname:te55~0.5
```

which is requesting to match **at least** one, but not forcing **both**.

You need to have query like this:

```
+postcode:te55~0.5 +buildingname:te55~0.5
```

The underlying problem in `MultiFieldQueryParser` is that by default it's making a should clauses. You need to `setDefaultOperator(AND_OPERATOR)` before, so you will get desired behaviour.

Some information related from Lucene.Net 3.0.3 - https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d6/d0b/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_query_parsers_1_1_multi_field_query_parser.html

Comment: You can see I've tried to do that "var formattedTermWildcard = $"+{formattedTerm}~";" but its not working. What is the syntax if what i have tried is not working out?